# Консоль выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу что бы кнопка скрывала панель аккродеона, однако даже рабочий скопированный код не работает и консоль выдает ошибку уберите скобки что бы перейти в песочницу https://codepen.io/sartaal/pen/PojpgjP

Вот сам код

```
document.getElementById('.menu-btn').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('#accordeon').classList.toggle('accordeon');`
  document.getElementById('#accordeon').classList.toggle('accordeon2');
}
```

Comment: `getElementById('.menu-btn')` - что означает точка в этом коде?

Comment: .menu-btn- это класс . Я неправильно его написал?

Comment: Это класс. А функция называется `getElementById`, a не `getElementByClass`. Странно.

Comment: Поставил кнопке id но ошибка осталась document.getElementById('#menu-btn').onclick = function()

Comment: если есть id `menu-btn`, то выборка идет так - `document.getElementById('menu-btn')`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.getElementById('.menu-btn').onclick = function() {
> ```

```
document.querySelector('.menu-btn').onclick = function() {
```

Comment: Исправил однако ошибка осталась та же

Comment: Селектор исправляй.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.